# SQL Server - Calculate Time Between Rows With Some Conditions

Tags: sql-server

I want to calculate time between multiple rows based on:

1. 1st: Name
2. 2nd: Type of event - The event has conditions itself because calculation should applied for 24 hours.

Conditions:

If first event was "Not Available", time should be calculated from 00:00:00 to the time of event.
Otherwise time will be calculated from difference between "Available" and the next "Not Available" or "Available".
If the last event was "Available", time will be calculated from the event time till 23:59:59

After all, sum of calculated time with some other information should be inserted to another table.

The table is looks like here:

| ID | Name | Type | Date-Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X1 | Not Available | 2021-03-30 04:12:00 |
| 2 | X1 | Available | 2021-03-30 08:12:00 |
| 3 | X1 | Available | 2021-03-30 10:12:00 |
| 4 | X1 | Not Available | 2021-03-30 11:32:00 |
| 5 | X1 | Available | 2021-03-30 20:30:00 |
| 6 | X2 | Available | 2021-03-30 08:30:00 |
| 7 | X2 | Not Available | 2021-03-30 18:12:00 |

Comment: Please elaborate and provide desired output - what does "first" imply - is that ordered by ID?

Comment: Should the "first" and "last" be grouped by Name? Will the time calculation ever cross over into different days or will they always be confined to the same day?

Comment: While your working on providing what the results should look like, check out LEAD() and LAG()

Comment: @Stu Not ordered by ID, I put the ID field for making the sample but it ordered by Name.

Comment: @jw11432 They will always same days from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59. Yes they should grouped by "Name"

Comment: @scsimon Yes, I saw some posts about them but I couldn't proper way to write the query. The problem is the first condition and also I don't know how can I do that for multiple names.

Comment: Still not getting it. What is "event"? Are you after time difference between first and last row for each group of names? You'll need to provide some examples and explain the logic.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got that appears to work. Double check that there isn't missing logic.

```
create table #test (ID int, Name varchar(4),    Type varchar(20),   DateTime datetime)

insert into #test values
('1',   'X1',   'Not Available',    '2021-03-30 04:12:00'),
('2',   'X1',   'Available',    '2021-03-30 08:12:00'),
('3',   'X1',   'Available',    '2021-03-30 10:12:00'),
('4',   'X1',   'Not Available',    '2021-03-30 11:32:00'),
('5',   'X1',   'Available',    '2021-03-30 20:30:00'),
('6',   'X2',   'Available',    '2021-03-30 08:30:00'),
('7',   'X2',   'Not Available',    '2021-03-30 18:12:00')



WITH CTE
 AS (SELECT *
          , Time = CAST(datetime AS TIME(0))
          , NextTime = LEAD(CAST(datetime AS TIME(0))) OVER(
            ORDER BY id)
          , RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name
            ORDER BY id)
     FROM #test),
 CTE2
 AS (SELECT *
          , first = CASE
                        WHEN RN = 1
                             AND type = 'Not Available' THEN CAST(Time AS TIME(0))
                    END
          , second = CAST(DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(second, datetime, LEAD(datetime) OVER(PARTITION BY name
                                      ORDER BY datetime)) * 1000, 0) AS TIME(0))
     FROM cte),
 CTE3
 AS (SELECT id
          , name
          , type
          , datetime
          , TimeDiff = ISNULL(first, second)
     FROM cte2),
 CTE4
 AS (SELECT name
          , TimeSum = CAST(DATEADD(ms, SUM(DATEDIFF(ms, '00:00:00.000', TimeDiff)), '00:00:00.000') AS TIME(0))
     FROM cte3
     WHERE type = 'available'
     GROUP BY name)
 SELECT cte3.*
      , cte4.TimeSum
 FROM cte4
      JOIN cte3 ON cte4.name = cte3.name
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems working. How can I have sum of time difference for each Name as one record and insert it to another table?

Comment: Would you please let me know, how can I calculate time for single record with "Available" type. It's not calculated.

Comment: Modified to have the time summed. Please accept my answer with the green check mark if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you but there is two problem, if I have single record with "Available" type, the time will not calculated for that. Another problem, last record has sum of time (Duration) but the new query will sum all other records and that. So total time is wrong.

Comment: You'll obviously need to tweak it. I've done 95% of the work for you, so that's a pretty good start. Your description did not give a comprehensive requirement list, so I did the best I could with what you provided.